# Exploiting structure of linear equations to solve them

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, matrix-equations

So I have a bunch of linear equations $Ax=y : A \in R^{m,m}, y \in R^{m}$. Note that $A$ is a square matrix. The question is if I can decompose $A$ as $$A = D + uv^T$$ where $D$ is diagonal, invertible, and $u,v \in R^N$. Would I be able to use the structure of this matrix to my advantage in solving the equation. My initial hunch was that it would somehow make #QR$ decomposition easier but I'm having trouble with this approach. Could someone point me in the right direction? I don't want an answer but just a simple clue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Sherman-Morrison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula:

$$(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1} - {A^{-1}uv^T A^{-1} \over 1 + v^T A^{-1}u}.$$

---

In your case, since $D$ is diagonal and invertible, the formula boils down to something quite simple. (Recall, the inverse of another diagonal matrix is a diagonal matrix with the reciprocals of the diagonal elements)